# Why do I get an undefined reference linking error with google test?

Tags: c++, c++11, googletest

I got the following very simple code snippet in C++11 which uses [Google Test](https://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html):

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include <iostream>

using ::testing::AtLeast; 

struct myStruct
{
    myStruct(){}
    ~myStruct(){}
};

class Turtle {
public:
    virtual ~Turtle() {}
    int f(myStruct& msg){std::cout<<__func__<<std::endl;}
};

class MockTurtle : public Turtle {
public:

    MOCK_METHOD(int, f, (myStruct&));

    void DelegateToFake() {

        ON_CALL(*this, f).WillByDefault([this](myStruct& msg)->int{
            std::cout<<"Hello world"<<std::endl;
        });
    }
};

TEST(myTest, foo) {

    MockTurtle mockTurtleObj;
    mockTurtleObj.DelegateToFake();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  ::testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

This is how I compile it:

```
g++ -Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra -Wno-reorder example.cpp -o example -lboost_system -lpthread -lboost_thread -lgmock -lgtest
```

Yet, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccju4zZ5.o: in function `void testing::internal::RawBytesPrinter::PrintValue<myStruct, 1ul>(myStruct const&, std::ostream*)':
example.cpp:(.text._ZN7testing8internal15RawBytesPrinter10PrintValueI8myStructLm1EEEvRKT_PSo[_ZN7testing8internal15RawBytesPrinter10PrintValueI8myStructLm1EEEvRKT_PSo]+0x33): undefined reference to `testing::internal::PrintBytesInObjectTo(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, std::ostream*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The whole output:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra -Wno-reorder example.cpp -o example -lboost_system -lpthread -lboost_thread -lgmock -lgtest
example.cpp: In member function ‘int Turtle::f(myStruct&)’:
example.cpp:16:57: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
   16 |     int f(myStruct& msg){std::cout<<__func__<<std::endl;}
      |                                                         ^
example.cpp:16:21: warning: unused parameter ‘msg’ [-Wunused-parameter]
   16 |     int f(myStruct& msg){std::cout<<__func__<<std::endl;}
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~^~~
example.cpp: In lambda function:
example.cpp:28:9: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
   28 |         });
      |         ^
example.cpp:26:58: warning: unused parameter ‘msg’ [-Wunused-parameter]
   26 |         ON_CALL(*this, f).WillByDefault([this](myStruct& msg)->int{
      |                                                ~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccju4zZ5.o: in function `void testing::internal::RawBytesPrinter::PrintValue<myStruct, 1ul>(myStruct const&, std::ostream*)':
example.cpp:(.text._ZN7testing8internal15RawBytesPrinter10PrintValueI8myStructLm1EEEvRKT_PSo[_ZN7testing8internal15RawBytesPrinter10PrintValueI8myStructLm1EEEvRKT_PSo]+0x33): undefined reference to `testing::internal::PrintBytesInObjectTo(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, std::ostream*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Could someone tell me what the matter is here?

Comment: If you read your message, you will see that you have declared it with return value `int`, but you don't return anything. Writing your function contents on new line will help you in the future

Comment: are you linking to the same version of gtest and gmock as in your header files? are the libraries built with the same compiler?

Comment: @vikAy I know but this doesnt explain the linking error

Comment: @AlanBirtles well I don't know I have not found a way to determine the versions...

Comment: You definitely compile with release-1.11.0 but link with release-1.10.0 or older.

Comment: @273K what makes you believe that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm relatively new to both C++ and CMake so I don't really know what your code is supposed to do, but I did manage to get it to run without errors. I'm using GoogleTest with CMake in my own project, a basic CMake script to make your code run looks like this (Just make sure you have CMake and Git installed):

project_root/CMakeLists.txt

```
project(gtest_test)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

# FetchContent
include(FetchContent)
Set(FETCHCONTENT_QUIET FALSE)

message(STATUS "Fetching GoogleTest")
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/google/googletest/"
  GIT_TAG "e2239ee6043f73722e7aa812a459f54a28552929"
  GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

# Creates the executable main_exe
add_executable(
    main_exe
    main.cpp
)

# Links the libraries to the executable
target_link_libraries(
    main_exe
    PRIVATE
        gtest_main
        gmock_main
)

include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(main_exe)
```

I made a small modification to your code to avoid the return error:

project_root/main.cpp

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include <iostream>

using ::testing::AtLeast; 

struct myStruct
{
    myStruct(){}
    ~myStruct(){}
};

class Turtle {
public:
    virtual ~Turtle() {}
    int f(myStruct& msg){
        std::cout<<__func__<<std::endl;

        return 0; // To avoid error
    }
};

class MockTurtle : public Turtle {
public:

    MOCK_METHOD(int, f, (myStruct&));

    void DelegateToFake() {

        ON_CALL(*this, f).WillByDefault([this](myStruct& msg)->int{
            std::cout<<"Hello world"<<std::endl;
            
            return 0; // // To avoid error
        });
    }
};

TEST(myTest, foo) {

    MockTurtle mockTurtleObj;
    mockTurtleObj.DelegateToFake();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  ::testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

To run it (I'm on Ubuntu):

- Go to project root (Where main.cpp and CMakeLists.txt are)
- mkdir build
- cd build
- cmake ../
- cmake --build .
- ./main_exe